# Using T4MVC in real project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

T4MVC is cool, but I have a couple of issues integrating it in my project, any help is really appriciated:

1. I've got such warnings for all my actions (I use `SnippetsBaseController` as base class for all my controller classes:

   Warning 26  'Snippets.Controllers.ErrorController.Actions' hides inherited member 'Snippets.Controllers.Base.SnippetsBaseController.Actions'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.   C:\projects_crisp-source_crisp\crisp-snippets\Snippets\T4MVC.cs   481 32  Snippets
2. Is it possible to have strongly typed names of custom Routes, for example, I have route defined like this:

   ```
       routes.MapRoute(
           "Feed",
           "feed/",
           MVC.Snippets.Rss()
       );
   ```

Is it possible to replace:

```
<%= Url.RouteUrl("Feed") %>
```

with something like:

```
<%= Url.RouteUrl(MVC.Routes.Feed) %>
```

3. Having strongly typed links to static files is really cool, but I use `<base />` in my pages, so I don't need any URL processing, can I redefine 
   `T4MVCHelpers.ProcessVirtualPath` without tweaking the `T4MVC.tt` itself?
4. T4MVC always generate links with uppercased controller and action names, for example:
   /Snippets/Add instead of /snippets/add. Is it possible to generate them lowercase?

Comment: Remember to always check developer's documentation: https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/wiki/Contributing#basic-description-of-the-t4mvc-solution

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Can you change your base controller class to be abstract?  I think that'll fix it.
2. See this post which discusses this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1535567.aspx
3. If you look in t4mvc.settings.t4, you'll see a ProcessVirtualPathDefault method that you can change without touching the main .tt file.
4. See http://forums.asp.net/t/1532057.aspx.  There is suggested fix in there, though it has not yet been submitted (but you can try it).

David

Comment: For (1). Switching to abstract base class helped, but one warning still active: 
`Snippets.Controllers.SnippetsController.View()' hides inherited member 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended`

Comment: I don't think T4MVC generates something called 'View'.  You're sure it's not something in your base controller itself?

Comment: Ahhr. it seems to be not T4MVC related, I have action called View(), I'll try to use [ActionName]. thanks for answering my fast and simple questions!